# EmberJS passing data to jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, ember.js

Can people please tell me the best way to pass an ember model to a jQuery plugin.

I would normally instantiate a jQuery model in the onDidInsert() function, but if my jQuery module needs to be passed dynamic model data then what is the best way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your view is for a route then you can [access the controller](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_view-context) and therefore your model.

```
// onDidInsert()
this.get('controller.model');
```

Else you'll first have to pass your model to the view, wherever you instance the view. At that point you'll `get()` it directly from the view.

```
<!-- *.hbs -->
{{view App.SomeView someName=this.model}}

// onDidInsert()
this.get('someName');
```

Of course there are different contexts when using a view but this should give you the general idea. If not, let me know how you are using the view.